# Trying to insert different HTML code in each pane of the Scrollify angularjs app

Tags: html, angularjs

So I've been trying to understand this AngularJS Scrollify directive and I I think I've understood it for the most part except for one thing.

I want to be able to insert different HTML for each pane in the array.

I've just been tinkering with the source for the app they provide on their website here: https://github.com/homerjam/angular-scrollify

I've changed it up a bit to it's essential parts:

```
<html>

<head>

    <title>angular-scrollify</title>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="example/styles.css">

</head>

<body ng-app="ExampleApp" ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">

    <div style="z-index: 1000;
                position: fixed;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100px;
                background-color: brown;">
    </div>

    <div class="scrollify"
        hj-scrollify="pane in data.panes"
         j-scrollify-options="{
            id: 'myScrollify'
        }">
        <!--j-scrollify-options="{
            id: 'myScrollify'
        }" PUT THIS BEFORE THE > AND AFTER THE " FROM ABOVE-->

        <div
            class="content"
            style="background-color: {{pane.color}}"
            ng-click="$scrollify.goTo($index)">
            <!--ng-attr-data-text="{{pane.name+pane.last}}" put in div above-->
        </div>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/hamsterjs/hamster.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/lethargy/lethargy.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/hammerjs/hammer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular-scrollify.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="example/app.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

But I want to be able to use different HTML for each pane. I went to the app.js file and tried to link an htm file to a variable in the scope so that I can use it in the hj-scrollify loop. hj-scrollify stores the array of data.panes in pane, and I want to be able to have a variable in data.pane that will display different html inside each given pane.

Here is the modified app.js code

```
angular.module('ExampleCtrl', []).controller('ExampleCtrl', ['$scope','$http',
    function($scope,$http) {

        $scope.data = {};

        $scope.data.panes = [
            {
                color: '#' + ('000000' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16)).slice(-6),
                name: "hon",
                last: "doe",
                html: ""
            },
            {
                color: '#' + ('000000' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16)).slice(-6),
                name: "son",
                last: "so",
                html: ""
            }
        ];

        $http.get("pane1.htm").then(function(d){
            $scope.data.panes[0].html=d.data;
        });


        /*for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {

            $scope.data.panes[i] = {
                text: i + 1,
                color: '#' + ('000000' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16)).slice(-6),
                customHTML: "<h1>Hi</h1>"
            };

        }*/

        $scope.top = function() {
            $scope.$broadcast('scrollify:goTo', {
                pane: 0,
                speed: 0,
                id: 'myScrollify' // optional
            });
        };

        $scope.$on('scrollify:change', function(event, args) {
            console.log(args);
        });

    }
]);

angular.module('ExampleApp', ['hj.scrollify', 'ExampleCtrl']).config(function() {});
```

I have a file called pane.htm that has some HTML: `<h1>I'm pane 1</h1>` and I want that to be displayed only on the first pane, then I'll set another file to data.pane[1].html and have that have different HTML.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I DID IT!

Okay so what I did was this:

1. I need to add $sce to the controller and function like this:

   ```
   angular.module('ExampleCtrl', []).controller('ExampleCtrl', ['$scope','$http','$sce',function($scope,$http,$sce)
   ```

2.
 Then when when I set the html code from the other files I do this:

```
    $http.get("pane1.htm").then(function(d){
        $scope.data.panes[0].html=$sce.trustAsHtml(d.data);
    });
```

3. In my HTML I put this:

   ```
   <div
       class="content"
       style="background-color: {{pane.color}}"
       ng-click="$scrollify.goTo($index)">
       <div ng-bind-html="pane.html"></div>
   </div>
   ```

And it works. Hopefully this helps someone since Scrollify is was pretty hard to understand for me.